# remove input size from html with preg_replace

Tags: php, parsing, preg-replace

I am using Simple HTML DOM Parser and with this I am able to get all input tags from object snippet is below

```
foreach ($InputObj->find('input') as $e) {

    $inputTag =  $e->outertext;

   // now I want to check if input element have size attribute then remove it with preg_replace
   $inputTagsSizeStrip = preg_replace('~\<input[^\s]*size=\'|\"[^\'|\"]~is', "" , $inputTag);
}
```

but no success....

any help will be appriciated...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no reason to use regular expressions here.  You already have the DOM, just do the necessary manipulation:

```
foreach ($InputObj->find('input') as $e) {
  if ($e->hasAttribute('size')) {
    $e->removeAttribute('size');
  }
}
```

Comment: yes man its working thanks I did not know that simple parser have that much of ability thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

you are already in input tag so no need to go for input tag to search for the size use this preg it will find the size and remove it

```
 foreach ($InputObj->find('input') as $e) {  
       $inputTagsSizeStrip = preg_replace('~(size=(\"|\')[^\'|\"]*(\"|\'))~is', $changeSrc , $inputTagsSizeStrip);
 }
```

it will definitely work

Comment: it also works Thanks but I am accepting sean bright's answer because he did it with the simple html parser